# Navigation Drawer Image Preview

Tags: android, android-studio

Kindly can any one tell me how could I display image to navigation drawer header by getting image from gallery.

When I click on image it opens gallery by using Glide library but after cropping it does not shows the image.

Comment: If you post your code, we will get your exact problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

1) `private ImageView imgProfile;`

2) `private static final String urlProfileImg = "Your URL";`

3) `imgProfile = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.img_profile);`

4)
`Glide.with(this).load(urlProfileImg)
                .crossFade()
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .bitmapTransform(new CircleTransform(this))
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imgProfile);`

Thats it!

Comment: I'm not sure if the question is even clear enough to provide a meaningful answer yet. By the way, you should put you code in a code block format instead of what you have here.

Comment: Add it in you OnClickListner with in your OnCreate or OnCreateView depending if you are using an Activity or Fragment.....